# ODI - COPY DATA FROM ONE DATA SOURCE TO ANOTHER WITH PROCEDURE

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have trying to create a procedure that will copy data from one data source to another with the use of a procedure.

I am not using mapping because in a later stage the table name will be populated in a parameter table.

I have tried to put below SQL in Source Command

Select * from table_a --From Data Source 1

and below in Target Command

Insert into table_b  --From Data Source 2

I know there is something missing in the target command but haven't been able to come across any source that can help.

thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

You should reference in the insert statement, the name of the columns with ":".

For example:

Source command:

```
select column1, column2, column3 from table_a
```

Target command:

```
Insert into table_b
(
column1,
column2,
column3
)
VALUES
(
:column1,
:column2,
:column3
)
```